# сортировка двумерного массива по количеству гласных

Tags: python

Как отсортировать такой массив по количеству гласных я сделал так

```
['My', 'name', 'is', 'Ivan']
res = sorted(arr, key=lambda word: sum(ch in "AOYUEIaoyuei" for ch in word), reverse=False)
print(res)
Ответ: ['My', 'is', 'name', 'Ivan']
```

А вот как отсортировать массив предложений по количеству гласных?
Вот такой массив например:

```
[['Ok, anything else?'], ['Aaaa'], ['My name is Nik']]
```

Чтобы результат был таким:

```
[['Aaaa'], ['My name is Nik'], ['Ok, anything else?']]
```

Я так понимаю, что принцип тот же. Сначала разбить внутренние массивы на двумерные, а потом проводить сортировку, но как это реализовать...
Я сделал свой собственный алгоритм сортировки, но опять же это для такого варианта:

```
arr = ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Ivan']
    for words in range(len(arr)):
        count = 0
        for letters in range(len(arr[words])):
            if arr[words][letters] in list_vowels:
                count += 1
        arr[words].append(count)
    arr.sort(key=lambda words: words[-1])
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# Вспомогательная функция для подсчёта гласных в одной строке
count_vowels_in_word = lambda word: sum(char in "AOYUEIaoyuei" for char in word)

# Вспомогательная функция для подсчёта гласных в списке строк
count_vowels_in_sequence = lambda seq: sum(map(count_vowels_in_word, seq))

src = [['Ok, anything else?'], ['Aaaa'], ['My name is Nik']]

print(sorted(
    src,  # Что сортируем
    key=count_vowels_in_sequence  # По чему сортируем
))
```

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь) Классное решение!

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска гласных нет разницы предложение или слово. И первое, и второе, просто набор символов, только в предложении присутствуют пробелы и знаки пунктуации, что на количество гласных не влияет. Так что подход в обоих случаях одинаковый.

```
# Убрал лишние скобки вокруг строк, зачем они нужны?
sentences = [
                'Ok, anything else?',
                'Aaaa',
                'My name is Nik'
            ]
# Преобразуем в 'set' для быстрого поиска
vowels = set("aeiouy")

print(sorted(sentences, key=lambda sentence: sum(1 for char in sentence if char.lower() in vowels)))
```

**Output**

```
['Aaaa', 'My name is Nik', 'Ok, anything else?']
```